# MX Master 3 with IntelliJ - back/forward buttons cause jump many times

Tags: intellij-idea, logitech

I have the MX Master 3 and use IntelliJ on Windows 10, latest Logitech software version 8.36.86.

In browsers, the Back/Forward buttons behave as expected and take me back/forward a single page in the tab history.

However in IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.3, they appear to take effect a large number of times and iteratively click back through all the remembered code locations, instead of just to the previous code location.

Plugging in an old Microsoft 5000 mouse doesn't have this issue, the back/forward buttons just take me to the previous/next code location. So it seems to be a problem with Master MX3, or some incompatibility with IntelliJ.

What can I do to diagnose this and fix it?

Comment: Do you have application-specific profile for IntelliJ turned on in Logitech Options?

Comment: No. I tried turning that on but none of the options seem to relate to the back/forward button.

Comment: Also I tried setting the back/forward shortcuts directly in IntelliJ for Button4/Button5 but they were already set and it made no difference

Answer (score 2):

Well the solution I have is to forcibly close and restart the "LogiOptions.exe (UNICODE)" application through Task Manager after which the back/forward buttons work normally. I have to do this about once a day for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a keystroke (Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right) in the Logitech Options app for back/forward buttons